# Issue with authorization on Coinigy V2 API

Tags: c#, http, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I have been working on a project and i used to use the v1 api for coinigy and loved the API. The problem is now with the new v2 API, I have been having an issue with trying to work the private API with the hmac_sha256 signature. I originally contacts coinigy support, but with little luck was not able to get it fully working (they did help, but never solved the issue, which is very weird). I built a simple test project in C# to perform a private call with the documentation they had for their api.

program.cs:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace coinigy_example
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string api_key = "API_KEY";
        string api_secret = "API_SECRET";
        CoinigyApiPrivateCall call = new CoinigyApiPrivateCall(api_key, api_decret);


        string data = call.HttpPostRequest("private/exchanges/" + "BINA" + "/markets/" + "BTC" + "/" + "LTC" + "/ticker", "", null, "GET");
        string body = null;
        call.xcoinApiCall("private/exchanges/" + "BINA" + "/markets/" + "BTC" + "/" + "LTC" + "/ticker", "", ref body);


        try
        {
            JObject j = JObject.Parse(data);

            TickerDataCoinigy tt = new TickerDataCoinigy();
            tt.volume = (string)j["volume"];
            tt.last = (string)j["last"];
            tt.high = (string)j["high"];
            tt.low = (string)j["low"];
            tt.ask = (string)j["ask"];
            tt.bid = (string)j["bid"];

            Console.WriteLine("Binance, BTC-LTC ticker data:");

            Console.WriteLine("Volume: " + tt.volume);
            Console.WriteLine("Last: " + tt.last);
            Console.WriteLine("High: " + tt.high);
            Console.WriteLine("Low: " + tt.low);
            Console.WriteLine("ask: " + tt.ask);
            Console.WriteLine("bid: " + tt.bid);
        }
        catch(Exception i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}

public class TickerDataCoinigy
{
    public string volume;
    public string last;
    public string high;
    public string low;
    public string ask;
    public string bid;
}
}
```

and also several versions (to see if a different way of calling the api would work) of a private call.

CoinigyApiPrivateCall.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace coinigy_example
{
public class CoinigyApiPrivateCall
{
    private string api_key;
    private string api_secret;

    public CoinigyApiPrivateCall(string api_key, string api_secret)
    {
        this.api_key = api_key;
        this.api_secret = api_secret;
    }

    public static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
        return Math.Floor(diff.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    private string Hash_HMAC(string sKey, string sData)
    {
        byte[] rgbyKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);


        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(rgbyKey))
        {
            byte[] inf = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sData));

            return (ByteToString(inf));
        }
    }

    private string ByteToString(byte[] rgbyBuff)
    {
        string sHexStr = "";


        for (int nCnt = 0; nCnt < rgbyBuff.Length; nCnt++)
        {
            sHexStr += rgbyBuff[nCnt].ToString("x2"); // Hex format
        }

        return (sHexStr);


    }

    private byte[] StringToByte(string sStr)
    {
        byte[] rgbyBuff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sStr);

        return (rgbyBuff);
    }



    public string HttpPostRequest(string url, string au, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postdata, string httpType)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ua);
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", api_key);
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-SECRET", api_secret);
        string time = Convert.ToString(ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()));
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = null;
        string data = null;
        if (postdata != null)
        {
            content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postdata);
            var output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postdata);
            data = api_key + time + httpType.ToUpper() + "/api/v2/" + url  + output;
        }
        else
        {
            data = api_key + time + httpType.ToUpper() + "/api/v2/" + url;
        }
        string sign = Hash_HMAC(api_secret, data);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-SIGN", sign);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-TIMESTAMP", time);

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        if (httpType.ToUpper() == "POST")
        {
            response = client.PostAsync("https://api.coinigy.com/api/v2/" + url, content).Result;
        }

        if (httpType.ToUpper() == "GET")
        {
            response = client.GetAsync("https://api.coinigy.com/api/v2/" + url).Result;
        }

        if (httpType.ToUpper() == "PUT")
        {
            response = client.PutAsync("https://api.coinigy.com/api/v2/" + url, content).Result;
        }

        if (httpType.ToUpper() == "DELETE")
        {
            response = client.DeleteAsync("https://api.coinigy.com/api/v2/" + url).Result;
        }



        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode
            ? response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
            : "ERROR:" + response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase + " | " + response.RequestMessage;
    }

    public JObject xcoinApiCall(string sEndPoint, string sParams, ref string sRespBodyData)
    {
        string sAPI_Sign = "";
        string sPostData = sParams;
        string sHMAC_Key = "";
        string sHMAC_Data = "";
        string sResult = "";
        double nNonce = 0;
        HttpStatusCode nCode = 0;


        sPostData += "&endpoint=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(sEndPoint);

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.coinigy.com/api/v2/" + sEndPoint);
            byte[] rgbyData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sPostData);


            nNonce = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());

            sHMAC_Key = this.api_secret;
            sHMAC_Data = api_key + nNonce.ToString() + "GET" +  "/api/v2/"   + sEndPoint;
            //sHMAC_Data = sEndPoint + (char)0 + sPostData + (char)0 + nNonce.ToString();
            sResult = Hash_HMAC(sHMAC_Key, sHMAC_Data);
            //sAPI_Sign = Convert.ToBase64String(StringToByte(sResult));
            sAPI_Sign = sResult;

            Request.Headers.Add("X-API-SIGN", sAPI_Sign);
            Request.Headers.Add("X-API-TIMESTAMP", nNonce.ToString());

            Request.Method = "GET";
            Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
            /*Request.ContentLength = rgbyData.Length;

            using (var stream = Request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(rgbyData, 0, rgbyData.Length);
            } */

            var Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

            sRespBodyData = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            return (JObject.Parse(sRespBodyData));
        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response)
            {
                nCode = Response.StatusCode;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    sRespBodyData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    try
                    {
                        return (JObject.Parse(sRespBodyData));
                    }
                    catch(Exception i)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (null);
    }



}
}
```

If anyone that has any knowledge on this that could help, I would be very grateful.

Edit: I used the code from Joe to see if the unauthorized issue could be fixed and I got this result:

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Sun, 29 Jul 2018 19:19:36 GMT
  Content-Length: 0
}}
```

I am using this code to perform the http call:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Coinigy_v2_api_2018.Functions;
   using System.Net.Http;

   namespace Coinigy_v2_api_test
   {
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ApiRequest req = new ApiRequest();
        req.BaseUrl = "https://api.coinigy.com";
        req.Body = "";
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.Secret = "secret";
        req.Key = "key";
        req.Endpoint = "/api/v2/private/exchanges";

        string signature = req.Signature;
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-SIGN", signature);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-TIMESTAMP", req.Timestamp);
            response = client.GetAsync(req.BaseUrl + req.Endpoint).Result;
        }
        string r = null;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            r = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
}
```

again thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API documentation can be found here: https://api.coinigy.com/api/v2/docs/#/

2019-08-28: Latest update is that the endpoint must require the query parameter unencoded when generating the signature.

The very first thing to check is to make sure you are using a V2 api key/secret. The old V1 keys will not work with the V2 api. If you upgrade your subscription, you will likely need to generate a new key for it to take effect.

Here is a class that should help out if that doesn't solve the problem:

```
public class ApiRequest
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();


    /// <summary>
    /// Each API request needs to be signed so the sender can be identified.
    /// This property generates the signature based on the current request.
    /// </summary>
    public string Signature
    {
        get
        {
            var asciiEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var hmac = new HMACSHA256(asciiEncoding.GetBytes(Secret));
            string signature = Key + Timestamp + Method.ToUpper() + Endpoint + (Body ?? string.Empty);
            byte[] signatureBytes = asciiEncoding.GetBytes(signature);
            byte[] hashedSignatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signatureBytes);
            string hexSignature = string.Join(string.Empty, Array.ConvertAll(hashedSignatureBytes, hb => hb.ToString("X2")));

            return hexSignature;
        }
    }
}
```

If you set those values properly, you should be able to generate the proper signature.

For the parameter values, start with something like this and compare to the signature I've produced to make sure your signature function is working properly:

```
BaseUrl   : https://api.coinigy.com
Endpoint  : /api/v2/private/exchanges?pythagoreanTheorem=a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%3Dc%5E2
Key       : keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeyke
Secret    : secretsecretsecretsecretsecretse
Method    : GET
Timestamp : 1532718830 (which is 2018-07-27T19:13:50.6694555Z)
Body      : (empty string)

Signature : B618C0B3C92632C701D7CEFC00AC9C8A0771989B21E00D61D4945F79239D2F87
```

Here is a bonus python3 version that will perform the entire process: https://gist.github.com/phillijw/1f78c8bafdce3a71a0b2ef9d4f5942a1

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks for helping me out! I am sadly still having the same issue with being unauthorized. I am going to add an edit with code that I have that is using your code you gave me. I get this result: {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 
    'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
    Headers:
    {
      Date: Sun, 29 Jul 2018 19:19:36 GMT
      Content-Length: 0
    }}

Comment: @ParkerBidigare You should have 3 headers but I only see two. The one you're missing is the X-API-KEY I think (not sure if that's the exact name of it)

Comment: I was referencing the v2 api and it only said two headers, do you remember where you saw the third header? I know in v1 api there are three.

Comment: @ParkerBidigare I work there which is why I know about it. It is not well documented at the moment. We will update the documentation to be more clear

Comment: could it be possible to get the additional api information by Friday or sooner?

Comment: @ParkerBidigare I've made changes to the docs that are ready to be released to production soon. THey might be there by Friday. If you want to work out the details before then, feel free to keep asking questions here or else hit me up on twitter or email or something. I'm fairly accessible

Comment: @ParkerBidigare Please see latest updates. I think this info is key to solving the problem

Comment: Could it be that the link that is meant to generate a V2 key/secret key actually generates a V1 key? Sounds trivial, but I have a feeling it could be an issue

Comment: @Timujin I haven't had any issues creating the v2 key through the website

Comment: Updated to fix the wrong signature (forgot to update it last time I made edits)